# Laravel 5 - real meaning of "sometimes" in validation rules

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel 5, let's consider those 2 different validation rules:

```
Validator::make($data, ['email' => 'sometimes|email']);
```

and

```
Validator::make($data, ['email' => 'email']);
```

After testing it:

- if $data['email'] exists and is a valid email => both will succeed.
- if $data['email'] exists and is not a valid email => both will fail.
- if $data does have an email key => both will succeed.

So what's the difference between those two rules? What's the purpose of "sometimes"?

Answer (score 6):

From Laravel's [validation docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#conditionally-adding-rules):

> In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the `sometimes` rule to your rule list.

So, essentially, `email` will only be validated if the field is actually part of the `POST` request.

This is particularly useful with the `required` rule, where the field will throw an error if left blank, but with `sometimes` will only do so if the field exists in the first place. Without `sometimes`, a missing physical field will **always** cause a "required field" error.

It's not something you'll need often, but it's a nifty little feature to have.

Comment: Ok so there is really no differences between the rule "sometimes|email" and the rule "email" right? "sometimes" is only useful when used in conjunction with "required" right?

Comment: The following rules are completely different: `required|email`, `sometimes|required|email`, and `email`. The first one fails if the input is empty, if the input is not a valid email address, and if there's no `email` input field. The second rule will fail **only** if you have an `email` input field. The third one will fail if the input is not a valid email address.

Comment: Everything you say is true and interesting. But my question is much simpler: i'm just comparing these two rules, and these two rules only: `sometimes|email` and `email`. You never talk about `sometimes|email` :) Do we agree those 2 ones are strictly equivalent?

Comment: From what I can tell digging around in Laravel's source, if the `sometimes` rule is set, the Validator checks if the field exists, and *only then* runs the other rules. So, if you don't have an email field, none of the other rules will ever be checked. If you do have such a field, however, the other rules will be checked normally. This means that if you always have the field, it will always be validated as if the only rule was `email`.

Comment: why they not call it optional

Answer (score 0):

Imagine simple form on your website. User can check if he wants to subscribe to newsletter and then he have to type email address. If he doesn´t want to subscribe, email field is disabled and isn´t send to server.
[image]

If

1. Validation rule is `'email' => 'email'` - in case form is submitted with empty email address, error message wil be:

> The email must be a valid email address.

2. Validation rule is `'email' => 'sometimes|required|email'` - in case form is submitted with empty email address, error message wil be:

> The email field is required.